# JS как вставить переменную вместо идентификатора для функции?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте уважаемые разработчики. Пишу на php и python, но порой сталкиваюсь с JS. Помогите, в простом казалось бы, коде:

```js
next.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p>' + text + '</p><hr>');
```

Так вот вместо next(идентификатор элемента) мне нужно динамически добавлять значение. Но ставлю переменную и выдаёт ошибку. Как обойти?
По факту попробовал так:

```js
idhr[0] = "next"; 
<hr id ='+idhr[0]+'> // html код на который ссылается функция ниже
idhr[0](insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p>' + text + '</p><hr>'));
// Ошибка: Uncaught ReferenceError: insertAdjacentHTML is not defined
```

Всё происходит внутри функции и цикла: вывожу данные из массива.

Comment: "... мне нужно динамически добавлять значение" - куда именно? Вы хотите вызвать другой метод объекта next или 'afterend' в переменной передавать? "...ставлю переменную и выдаёт ошибку" - что и куда ставите и какую ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: next  - идентификатор для html  тегов. Функция после НЕГО вставляет нужный мне элемент (<p>' + text + '</p><hr>). И я хочу при каждой итерации цикла менять идентификатор для которого выполянется эта функция.

Comment: Ну а сам 'next' у Вас откуда берётся? И как понять "... идентификатор для html тегов"? У Вас есть элемент с id next? Или next это уже [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element)? Также Вы так и не написали какую ошибку выдаёт.  
Согласно [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) позиции 'beforebegin' и 'afterend' работают только если узел имеет родительский элемент. Может ошибка в этом? P.S.: уточнения и пояснения к вопросу лучше добавлять непосредственно в вопрос, а не писать в комментариях.

Answer (score 1):

Для динамического обращения к имени используются `[]` квадратные скобки

```
next[variableName](arguments)
```

И да, БЕЗ точки после имени.

Также заходят и динамические цепочки

```
[some][nested][very][deep][name]()
```

которые конечно же отвалятся, если хоть один из ключей не существет

Comment: next[variableName](arguments) -  такая конструкция не работает в моём случае.

Comment: Можно пример вызова?

Comment: idhr[0] = "next";  idhr[0](insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p>' + text + '</p><hr>'));

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Использование с определёнными Id
var elemIds = ["elem1","elem2","elem3"];
for(var i = 0; i < elemIds.length; i++) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(elemIds[i]);
  elem.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p class="text-blue">' + elem.innerText + '*</p>');
}

// Использование с классом
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('p.text-grey');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  elems[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p class="text-blue">' + elem.innerText + '*</p>');
}
```

```css
p {
  padding: 1px 2px;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.text-red { color: red; }
.text-blue { color: blue; }
.text-grey { color: grey; }
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="elem1" class="text-red">One</p>
  <p id="elem2" class="text-red">Two</p>
  <p id="elem3" class="text-red">Three</p>
</div>
<hr/>
<div>
  <p class="text-grey">One</p>
  <p class="text-grey">Two</p>
  <p class="text-grey">Three</p>
</div>
```